# Why was Forever cancelled?

Tags: forever

The TV-Show *[Forever](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_(U.S._TV_series))* was recently cancelled by the ABC after only 1 season.

**What is the reason for the cancellation?**

The only thing I can find is a tweet from Alice Evans ([Ioan Gruffudd's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioan_Gruffudd) wife):

[image: Image capture of 'tweet' by Aice Evans announcing the cancellation of the TV-show, Forever]
<sup>[src: http://tvbythenumbers.zap2it.com/2015/05/07/forever-cancelled-by-abc-after-one-season/400839/ ]</sup>

My research includes:

- [**Show's official site**](http://abc.go.com/shows/forever)
- **[IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3487382/)**
- **[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_(U.S._TV_series))**

Comment: [this](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/abc-2014-15-season-ratings-33937/) is probably the reason. note the low ratings in the key 18-49 demographic.

Comment: @phantom42 Cool, thanks mate; and I followed the links down the rabbit-hole and found [this](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/forever-tv-show-cancelled-by-abc-no-season-two-36475/).

Comment: there are only ever two reason a TV Show gets cancelled: it has bad ratings, or its actors want too much $$. If it never makes it past season 1, it's bad ratings.

Comment: The ratings were about 100%, however, in the 200-10000 demographic.

Comment: Because ABC is run by idiots

Comment: If you don't know what it's about, it's about money. Low ratings means low ad income which means income can't pay production expenses. Or maybe they just think they can use the time slot for something yielding more net income.

Comment: Because of irony.

Comment: @RogueJedi [Here's a nice explanation of irony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YqXKrAyfEE) :p

Comment: Perhaps someone realized the program was just a bad version of [Forever Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forever_Knight).

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo: Haha, It does sound like it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The show was cancelled due to the following reasons:

> Though the Forever series had some very passionate fans, that devotion didn’t translate into positive ratings. The numbers were pretty poor for much of the season and the show ended up averaging a 1.12 rating in the 18-49 demographic with 4.93 million viewers.
>   As a result, ABC has decided against ordering a second season of Forever.

You can read it [here](http://tvseriesfinale.com/tv-show/forever-tv-show-cancelled-by-abc-no-season-two-36475/)

It was an amazing show and I'm sorry to see it cancelled :-(

Comment: Well you should have *made* your friends love it too :D

Comment: I live in the Netherlands, that wouldn't have made a difference